# Tableau formula Help (new user v repeat user etc)

Tags: tableau-api

Hi I am trying to figure out how to write the proper calculation.

My objective is to determine news versus repeat users by month using an email address as the identifier.

If an email address occurs once they would be counted one time as a new customer. If their email address occurs a second time and a third or fourth etc, I would want them to be counted as a repeat customer one time only for each month they purchased.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a calculated field that should solve this. It will require that you include the `Month` and `User` fields in your view. I added `Month to my columns and`User` to my rows and it worked fine.

```
 IF COUNTD([email]) > 1 THEN "Repeat" 
 ELSE "New"
 END
```

Comment: I had used that originally prior to asking the question. However each repeat is considered +1 when summing up the customers. I need to figure out a way to consider all repeats just as 1 customer and 1 count only not multiple times.